# Correlation structure corAR1() "not defined" in rpy2 generalised least squares model gls

Tags: python, rpy2

I'm using the rpy2 module in python to calculate regressions between two timeseries (ts1 and ts2).  The residuals are autocorrelated, so I need to use the gls model rather than lm. I should be able to set my correlation structure as corAR1() as in the code below.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import FloatVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

nlme = importr('nlme')

y = FloatVector(ts1)
x = FloatVector(ts2)
fmla = robjects.Formula('y ~ x - 1')
env = fmla.environment
env['x'] = x
env['y'] = y
fit = nlme.gls(fmla, cor=corAR1(value=c(0.5)))
```

However, I get the error

```
*** NameError: name 'corAR1' is not defined
```

As I'm not an R user and very new to rpy2, I'm not sure what's going on here! Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Felicity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when calling `importr('nlme')`, the object returned is like a Python package/namespace.
If `corAR1()` is defined in the `nlme` package, you should tell Python that it is there:

```
fit = nlme.gls(fmla, cor=nlme.corAR1(value=c(0.5)))
```